# swift transform mask to another mask with animation

Tags: swift, uiviewanimation

I want to change mask in animation

but it just like change to another mask without animation
[screen record](https://media.giphy.com/media/PO7JN5dcHJ9FlFE9dU/giphy.gif)

I want it look like [this](https://media.giphy.com/media/ipZSvbXZuW5ABq9AM8/giphy.gif)

```
func creatMask(_ index: Int) -> CALayer {
    let layer = CALayer()
    let image = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bubble_1.png"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bubble_2.png"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bubble_3.png"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bubble_4.png"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "bubble_5.png")]
    layer.contents = image[index].cgImage
    layer.contentsScale = image[index].scale
    layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    return layer
}

@objc func transform() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.redView.layer.mask = self.creatMask(1)
    }
}

}
```